# I am practicing automation using Selenium Webdriver. I want to put a date in a datepicker 7 days from today's date

Tags: java, date, selenium, datepicker, webdriver

I want to set a date in datepicker in one of the test sites. The date should be 7 days from today. For this i m using follwing function. In eclipse console window, SOP is pritning correct date but when I use the same with SendKeys command to website, it is not taking this string date. The code is as follows:

```
public static String Date7(){
        //a function to give date + 7 days
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); // Adding 7 days from current date 
        String CheckInDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        System.out.println(CheckInDate);
        return CheckInDate;}

public static void searchHotel(){
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
    wd.get("http://adactin.com/HotelApp/index.php");
    wd.findElement(By.id("datepick_in")).sendKeys(Date7());
}
```

After this, the site gets todays date, and not the date after 7 days.
Kindly help.

Comment: Well, your static method `Date7()` works fine although I would prefer small letter at start for example "dateOneWeekLater()". So your problem is on another location.

Comment: the datepicker input may be restricted to keys input. Paste your value using js

Comment: Hi Alexander, could you please provide me with the code for that js? or may be point me towards some example which I can refer...

Comment: I also tried returning date to a new string value and then calling it in webDriver script as follows

`String chekInDate = Date7();
wd.findElement(By.id("datepick_in")).sendKeys(chekInDate);`

so as to give direct string input and method input, but did not work...!!!:(